# Set up on Adafruit Motor Hat

Tags: driver, wiring

[image]

I recently bought the [Adafruit Stepper Motor Hat,](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2348) installed the [software as per the instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-dc-and-stepper-motor-hat-for-raspberry-pi), and while it works flawlessly when running the DC motor, it will only turn the stepper motor in one direction.  I honestly have no idea where to look for the problem - is is possible to hook up a stepper motor so that it will only run in one direction?

Update - I am using the [Lightobject EMOT-42HSM03 NEMA 17 42HSM03 Stepper Motor, Dual Shaft](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VA7JDZK) motor

Comment: We can only guess, as you have provided no details of the stepper, no details of how you have connected the stepper, and no details of the software you are using.

Comment: I am away from it now - photos coming soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the motor was defective, not sure how, but I have tried several others and it works like a charm.